# How to find a value within a JSONObject/Array Lookup

Tags: java, android, json

Below is the JSON feed:

```
    {
"list" : { 
"meta" : { 
"type" : "resource-list",
"start" : 0,
"count" : 2
},
"resources" : [ 
{
"resource" : { 
"classname" : "Quote",
"fields" : { 
"name" : "USD/KRW",
"price" : "1151.295044",
"symbol" : "KRW=X",
"ts" : "1437357550",
"type" : "currency",
"utctime" : "2015-07-20T01:59:10+0000",
"volume" : "0"
}
}
}
,
{
"resource" : { 
"classname" : "Quote",
"fields" : { 
"name" : "SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY",
"price" : "0.067476",
"symbol" : "XAG=X",
"ts" : "1437169614",
"type" : "currency",
"utctime" : "2015-07-17T21:46:54+0000",
"volume" : "62"
}
}
}
,
{
"resource" : { 
"classname" : "Quote",
"fields" : { 
"name" : "USD/VND",
"price" : "21815.500000",
"symbol" : "VND=X",
"ts" : "1437357540",
"type" : "currency",
"utctime" : "2015-07-20T01:59:00+0000",
"volume" : "0"
}
}
}

]
}
}
```

How do I go about finding the "price" of the JSON object who's symbol is ("symbol" : "XAG=X") for example. In this case the answer is ("price" : "0.067476"). I need to perform this lookup programatically since the JSON is rather larger than the one presented here and the only parameter given to me will be the "symbol".

Is this possible? Any detailed help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what about using Gson, or Jackson parsers?, i think you should learn that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is your Json object Format**

[image]

**Try this for getting correct result -**

```
JSONObject list = new JSONObject(content).getJSONObject("list");
JSONArray resources = list.getJSONArray("resources");
for (int j = 0; j < resources.length(); j++) {
  JSONObject resource = resources.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("resource");
  JSONObject fields = resource.getJSONObject("fields");
    if(fields.getString("symbol").equals("XAG=X")){
       System.out.println("Price of symbol(XAG=X) is"+ fields.getString("price"));
    }    
}
```

Comment: @TusharPatil, can you guide as to how to get the json format that you have posted as it would be helpful for long json messages?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming content represents the json string

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject list = new JSONObject(content).getJSONObject("list");
JSONArray resources = list.getJSONArray("resources");
for (int j = 0; j < resources.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject resource =     resources.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("resource");
    JSONObject fields = resource.getJSONObject("fields");
    System.out.println(fields.get("symbol"));
    System.out.println(fields.get("price"));
}
```